# My bitcoin transactions has not been confirmed after 24 hours. This is strange kindly help.

Tags: bitcoin-core

My bitcoin transactions on blockchain wallet  has not been confirmed after 24 hours. This is strange kindly help.
I used the standard fee proposed by blockchain wallet. 
This is my transaction here https://blockchain.info/tx/31739044f5bfdceab883ab2fcafd3096647ad2e0ca0c499465d9bd7982003905

Comment: The Bitcoin network is congested as hell right now.  
Over 200000+ unconfirmed-transactions https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions  
And your fee at 136 sat/B is lower than the average https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/

Comment: What do you suggest I do to resolve this, since bitcoin transactions cannot be edited

Comment: There are som suggestions here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it                                                   So you can either try to abandon the transaction or try to double-spend it with a higher fee(only works if you have sufficient amount and sent from the same address).